# Custom text field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, textfield

I am working on a site that has to have a box on the top left with a "welcome" header (h1) and text (p). I don't want to use a specific blog post for the content if there is a better way to do it.

How can I make this happen? A screenshot is shown in the following picture. Oh and I'm not a Vanilla Ice  fan ;)

[image]

Comment: If it is just a one box. You may add it in settings area of your theme. Saying `Welcome Box Text`.

Comment: assign widget area and put text from available widgets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a great place to add a widget area. Very easy to do. Refer to this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The solution I came up with is fairly simple - I just put a code of sidebar holder there (copied the original one and changed its ID) to make it visible as another sidebar in WP admin panel. Then I just added a HTML widget and put content there.